# Converting varchar to decimal baseball average

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I uploaded a CSV which automatically converted all my columns to varchar. I need to convert the value 22.30 to 0.223.

```
alter table badv2018
    alter column [BB Percent] decimal(4, 3)
```

But I get the error:

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 8, Line 146
>   Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.

Comment: This is great thanks. I've run into the issue when trying to do the same with the value 16.50. I get the error 'Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '16.50' to data type int. But I tried using alter table bplateinfo2018
Add [O-Swing Percent] as Cast([O-Swing%] / 100 as Decimal (4,3)); Then when I select * from bplateinfo2018, I get the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I need to convert the value 22.30 to 0.223.

You need to devide it by 100.0, then `DECIMAL(4, 3)` will be OK

```
DECLARE @Value DECIMAL(4, 3) = 22.3 / 100.0;

SELECT @Value
```

**Returns:**

```
0.223
```

So, you need to `UPDATE` your table first, then `ALTER` the `[BB Percent]` column.

The easy way is:

- Add new column `DECIMAL(4, 3)`.
- Move the data into it.
- Drop the old column.
- Rename the new one.

---

```
--First step
ALTER TABLE badv2018
ADD New DECIMAL(4, 3);

--Second step
UPDATE badv2018
SET New = [BB Percent] / 100.0;

--Third step
ALTER TABLE badv2018
DROP COLUMN [BB Percent];

--The last step
EXEC sp_rename 'badv2018.New', 'BB Percent', 'COLUMN';
```

Enjoy!

**[Live Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2a0fb51de7211ea5c047cead0903395d)**

---

*UPDATE:*

You can also add a computed column and leave the `[BB Percent]` column, this way will ensure you can get the real data and the computed one.

```
ALTER TABLE badv2018
ADD New AS CAST([BB Percent] / 100.0 AS DECIMAL(4, 3));
```

Comment: Needs putting in the context of altering the data and datatype in and existing table.

Comment: @MatBailie I think I leave nothing out :)

Comment: `(4,3)` can't hold both `22.3` and `0.223`.

Comment: @MatBailie See the live demo. `DECIMAL(4, 3)` can hold `0.223`.

Comment: But it can't hold 22.3

Comment: @MatBailie Yes, it can't hold `22.3` thus I write an update.

Comment: @MatBailie - it doesn't need to hold `22.3` because that value is in the original column. This answer proposes adding a new column that will never have to hold that value

Comment: This is great thanks. I'm trying to convert 6.80 to 0.068, but I use the above steps and get 'Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '6.40' to data type int.
' Any help? Thanks in advanced

Comment: @wickedflow So you are storing numbers as string which is bad, Always use the proper datatype for your data. Are `[BB Percent]` is really varchar?

Comment: @wickedflow Also does this error occur when you did what is on my answer or when you try to insert new data to `badv2018` table?

Comment: @sami when I insert new data.

Answer (score 2):

Make it a wider value.  For instance:

```
alter table badv2018
    alter column [BB Percent] decimal(10, 3)
```

`(4, 3)` can only represent values from 0.000 to 9.999.  You probably really want `(6, 3)`, so 10 is overkill.

You can then add another column with the result you want:

```
alter table badv2018
    add column bb_ratio as ([BB Percent] / 100);
```

Comment: `I need to convert the value 22.30 to 0.223.`. So, also needs an update statement, and possibly a second alter column